# what is the diffrence between render and a normal function in reactjs components

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, render

when I click the button render works and print in the console 'render works !' but NormalFn don't work why ? and what is the difference between them ?

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        const n = this;
        this.state = {
            bla: "maaa"
        };
        this.change = function(){
            if(n.state.bla == "maaa"){n.setState({bla:"ko"})}
            else {n.setState({bla:"maaa"})}
        }
    }
    
    NormalFn(){console.log('NormalFn works !')}
    
    render(){
        console.log('render works !');
        return <div>
            {this.state.bla}
            <button onClick={this.change}>change</button>
            </div>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Hello ka="haaaa"/>,document.getElementById("k"));
```

Comment: Internally React calls the class method called `render`. When you use a library or framework, you must follow their requirements.

Comment: i know every single time i click on the button only the class method called render will be called by React , but the issue why it calls just the class method called render and not the other class methods

Comment: Why would it? If you want another method to be called then **you** need to call it. React is only responsible for calling `render`, and other lifecycle methods. It doesn't make sense for it to call anything else..